# perl script explanation please

Tags: perl

> Write a perl program that reads in a text file containing
>   one word per line. Create a hash containing the words read as 
>   keys and the number of times they have been read as the value.
>   Print out each word and its frequency.

```
print $ARGV[0]."\n";

open (FILE,$ARGV[0]);
while ($line = <FILE>)
{
        chomp($line);
        if (exists($count{$line}))
        {
            $count{$line}++;
        }
        else
        {
            $count{$line} = 1;
        }
}

while ( ($word,$occurrences) = each(%count))
{
    print $word."  ".$occurrences."\n";

}
```

1. Shouldn't it be `open INFILE` instead of `FILE`?
2. `$count{$line}`: what is the role of `$count` in here? Can't you just write `$line++`?
3. Can you please explain this sentence?

   ```
   while ( ($word,$occurrences) = each(%count))
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. The name given to the filehandle doesn't have any special meaning. Except perhaps when using `STDOUT`, `STDIN` or `STDERR` as filehandle names. `FILE` works the same as `INFILE`, though some people may prefer `INFILE` for readability. See Mat's tip below for a valuable insight into the matter of filehandles.
2. `%count` is the hash that will be used to store the number of occurrences for each word.
3. Perldoc page for `each` [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html). Basically, this line iterates over the key-value pairs of the hash and assigns the key to the `$word` variable and the key's value in the hash to the `$occurrences` variable.

Comment: Extra tip: [Do not use bareword filehandles](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/perl/FIO00-PL.+Do+not+use+bareword+file+handles)

Comment: for number two, i was asking about $line, not %count

Comment: Well `$line++` by itself would do no good. It would actually produce a nonsensical value by "incrementing" the last character in the variable. Remember that `$line` actually contains the contents of the file's line not the line number. What is done here, is that the `%count` hash entry keyed by the contents of the `$line` variable is incremented (because the number of occurrences has increased by one) and created with a value of '1' if it didn't exist before.

Comment: @JosephR. ONe more question. what would be the $word keyvariable in here and $occurences keyvalue refer to in this example? thank you again!

Comment: `$word` would be a word read from the file (this example seems to assume an input file with one word per line) and `$occurrences` would contain the number of times this word has occurred in the file because it's incremented every time the `$word` is encountered.